# In WPF, video player which allows bearer token

Tags: wpf, sharepoint, access-token

I added a video player in WPF with the MediaElement tag.
I would like to access to a sharepoint video via the Video REST API. I have the token but I don't know how to pass this token in the request to get the video.
Is there a way to use a video player in WPF with a source accessible through an API which needs a token?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Is the video from that token available as a media object or as a stream? Have you tried to assign the url to `MediaElement.Source` property?

Comment: @pix I try to display a video hosted on sharepoint using the Video REST API.

Comment: @Peter weirdly set the Source brings me a System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'  
But if I access to my video url through a browser it brings me an "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." because I didn't pass the token. If I did it works.